# SQL Server 2008 R2 hacer Actualizacion en diferente Like

Tags: sql, sql-server

Muchos ya sabemos que (Like '%busque%') nos sirve en sql server para buscar palabras claves en esta oportunidad tengo que hacer esto:

```
UPDATE Table SET a.ItemID = 1000, a.type = 1, a.typeID = 0
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems a
INNER JOIN PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items b
ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
WHERE b.reqLevel Between 31 and 60 -- pero en la siguiente linea necesito omitir un file cuya palabra clave es Rockero
and b.ItemName  DIFERENT Like '%Rokero%'-- ¿seria asi como lo tengo que hacer? osea el cambi  tiene que ser en todo menos en lo que contenga palabra Rockero.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE Table SET a.ItemID = 1000, a.type = 1, a.typeID = 0
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.CharItems a
INNER JOIN PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items b
ON b.ItemID = a.ItemID
WHERE b.reqLevel Between 31 and 60 -- pero en la siguiente linea necesito omitir un file cuya palabra clave es Rockero
and b.ItemName NOT Like '%Rokero%'
```

En lugar de `DIFFERENT LIKE` es `NOT LIKE`.